# Implicitly scoped context in multi-threaded MVVM application

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-of-work

I'm working on a WPF application with heavy multi-threading using a bit of async/await.  I'm pondering the use of Unit of Work pattern (with implicit scoping) within the client (having it work much like a TransactionScope), but can't decide where to store the context.

Some things I've considered:

- Thread locals; but that won't work as we may switch threads in a nested unit of work.
- Static; I believe this will fail if two unrelated unit of works are executed at the same time

In my service layer (webapi odata), I attach the unit of work to the http context to allow nesting across threads.  Has anyone tried something like this in a client app and have a decent way of scoping nested units of work?

Comment: I think that the safest way to go is for every `Task`/`Thread` to create its own unit of work (be it `ISession`, `DbContext` or whatever else you might have), mostly because none of these solutions are inherently thread safe. Unless, of course, you have hand-rolled UoW that's thread safe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit of Work doesn't necessarily mean that the context is implicit (or scoped, for that matter). I believe it's quite normal for UoW to be explicit (e.g., your BO types would keep a reference to their "owning" context, which is itself threadsafe). That said, an implicit context is possible with `async`.

When you use `await` only in an ASP.NET request context, the best option is to use `HttpContext.Items`. Alternatively, you could use threadsafe static members.

When you use `await` only in a UI context, you could use regular static members.

When you use multithreading, you could use thread locals.

However, if any of your code uses multithreading *with* `await` (e.g., `ConfigureAwait(false)`, or passing an `async` lambda to `Task.Run`), then none of those options will work.

AFAIK, there is only one general solution, which [I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html): `CallContext.LogicalGetData` and `CallContext.LogicalSetData`. The logical call context will flow across threads and would work in any `async` situation.

There are some limitations to this approach:

1. You must use the .NET 4.5 framework. `CallContext` was made `async`-aware in .NET 4.5, so if you're targeting .NET 4.0 / Phone / Silverlight, this won't work correctly.
2. You should only store immutable data. This is made much easier if you use [Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Nice blog and great info. I'm currently targeting 4.0 [to support XP :-(], but will file this away for future reference.

Comment: Ah. Unfortunately, an `async`-compatible implicit scoped context isn't available for .NET 4.0. :(